# Adaptive learning rate Lasagne

Tags: theano, deep-learning, lasagne

I am using Lasagne and Theano library to build my own deep learning model following the MNIST example. Can anyone please tell me how the adaptively change the learning rate?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend having a look at https://github.com/Lasagne/Lasagne/blob/master/lasagne/updates.py.

If you are using sgd, then you can use a momentum term (e.g. https://github.com/Lasagne/Lasagne/blob/master/lasagne/updates.py#L156) to adaptively change the learning rate. If you want to make anything non-standard, the momentum implementation give you enough hints how to create something similar on your own.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way of doing this is by creating a theano shared variable for your learning rate, passing the shared variable to the updates function and changing through the set_value method, as follows:

```
lr_shared = theano.shared(np.array(0.1, dtype=theano.config.floatX))
updates = lasagne.updates.rmsprop(..., learning_rate=lr_shared)

...

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    if epoch % 10 == 0:
        lr_shared.set_value(lr_shared.get_value() / 10)
```

Of course you can change the optimizer and the if codition, this is just an example.